# mv files with multiple `.` in the file name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, mv

I have some files I receive with names like (to many to do this manually everyday):

```
AA.B.txt
WW.C.txt
```

and I want to rename them to `AA_B.txt` and `WW_C.txt` so that existing SQL code still functions as expected. Right now these files are ignored due to the filename.letter.txt format.

`ls` works and shows me these files:

```
$ ls -a *.*.txt
AA.B.txt*
ABR.A.txt*
ABR.B.txt*
ABR.C.txt*
ACT.A.txt*
```

However a similar `mv` command fails:

```
$ mv *.*.txt *_*.txt
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

How do I match the pattern I have with what I want?

Comment: Note: in `mv *.*.txt *_*.txt` the `*.*.txt` part behaves like in `echo *.*.txt`; the `*_*.txt` part behaves like in `echo *_*.txt`. There is no logical connection between the first asterisk and the third, nor between the second and the fourth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv` is not the right tool.

You should use the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/\./_/' *.*.txt
```

The string `'s/\./_/'` means "substitute the **first** occurrence of a `.` with a `_` in the folling file list".

Comment: Oh.  I did not know about the rename command.  Very nice.

Comment: Wow. Installed `rename` and this worked perfectly. Now to read `man rename`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The mv command can only have one target, either renaming one file (e.g. mv AA.B.txt AA_B.txt) or moving a set of files and directories into a directory (e.g. mv *.*.txt *newdir*).  If you want to rename a file, you need to do it one at a time.  So, some kind of loop.

Try something like the following:

```
for f in *.*.txt; do
    mv ${f} $(echo ${f} | sed -e 's#\.#_#')
done
```

The sed command replaces just the first dot found with an underscore.  Any remaining dots are untouched.

Hope this helps.